# How to program keystrokes on a single app in Windows after minimizing?

Tags: autohotkey, minimize, minimized

I'm able to program certain automated tasks using AutoHotKey but it requires that I have the app window open. In other words, I can't Alt+Tab away from the app or else the AutoHotKey script won't work.

Is there a way I can program certain keystrokes and mouse movements to an app on Windows so that those keystrokes continue to function even after I minimize (or Alt+Tab away) the app?

From similar questions I've found here, creating a bot seems to be the best way to do this, but would a bot work on a minimized program (running in the background)?

Answer (score 1):

You can send commands to a specific application with **[ControlSend](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm)** and **[ControlClick](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm)**.

> #### [ControlSend](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm)
>
> Sends simulated keystrokes to a window or control.
>
> *Examples*
>
> ```
> ControlSend, Edit1, This is a line of text in the notepad window., Untitled
> SetTitleMatchMode, 2
> ControlSend, , abc, cmd.exe  ; Send directly to a command prompt window.
> ```

> #### [ControlClick](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm)
>
> Sends a mouse button or mouse wheel event to a control.
>
> *Examples*
>
> ```
> ControlClick, OK, Some Window Title  ; Clicks the OK button
> ControlClick, x55 y77, WinTitle  ; Clicks at a set of coordinates. Note the lack of a comma between X and Y.
>
> ; The following method may improve reliability and reduce side effects:
> SetControlDelay -1
> ControlClick, Toolbar321, WinTitle,,,, NA x192 y10  ; Clicks in NA mode at coordinates that are relative to a named control.
> ```